# AndroidDriver startactivity method relaunches the application

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

My aim is to click on button 7 in Android calculator, click on add button, click on button 6. Then switch the application to settings. Switch back to calculator and verify 13 is displayed in calculator.

I have the below code:

```
AndroidDriver mobileDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
mobileDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.android.calculator2:id/digit_7']")).click();
mobileDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.android.calculator2:id/op_add']")).click();
mobileDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.android.calculator2:id/digit_6']"))
                        .click();
mobileDriver.startActivity("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings");
mobileDriver.startActivity("com.android.calculator2","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
String result = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.android.calculator2:id/result']")).getText();
Assert.assertEquals("Incorrect Result", "13", result);
```

But here when I switch back to calculator result is not displayed. I think its relaunching the application.Any way to resume from the previously switched point.

Answer (score 0):

using adb in your code to launch settings and then launch the calculator will do the job for you 
U can use 
Adb shell pm launch activity settings 
Adb shell pm launch activity your activity name 
Also check if ur providing apk or just activity name in your desired caps 
If ur providing apk then change it to app activity and package name in desired caps